# How to add tax amount in old orders in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, tax

I have some orders is placed, when tax rule is not build. After some times, I will create tax rule. Now all orders is placed with tax rules. But I want to add tax rule in old orders. How can I do this in Magento-2.1 ? Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Logically, it should not be ***implemented as Magento does not recalculate total and other price-related with an order***.

As an e-commerce view, it is not ***good logic to tax after orders. Tax changes after order place make a user confuse and it becomes create trust issue over the website.***

**In my point of view, if you want to change the tax amount why you do not cancel old order and create the new orders from admin for those orders.**

Comment: This is **Bold** & Beautifull answer ;)

Comment: @Amit, but can we set any custom fixed tax_amount on quote item? if its possible please update to my question here, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart